# Bind the same property to two checkboxes

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two checkboxes in my page and i want to assign the checked checkbox value to my property. Right now i have created the checkboxes but when i bind them to same property they start triggering together in the view which i do not want. I have the `alignment` property which will be either getting value of left or right checkbox. How can i achieve this?

```
<div class="row clearfix">
 <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">
    Left 
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
     <input id="someSwitchOptionDefault" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="addProfile.alignment"/>
      <label for="someSwitchOptionDefault" class="label-default"></label>
      </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
   Right
   <div class="material-switch pull-right">
   <input id="switch" name="switch" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="addProfile.alignment"/>
   <label for="switch" class="label-default"></label>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to use 2 distinct variables

Comment: What do you want the behaviour to be? If the 2 checkboxes are set to different values, what should `alignment` be set to?

Comment: there is a right labelled checkbox and there is a left labelled checkbox. I have a paragraph here which will be placing itself in the page by taking in the value of alignment property. So if it will be left then paragraph will be placed on the left and if right then paragraph on left side of page. So i am just trying to bind `alignment` property with both checkboxes so that if one checkbox is checked then its value will be assigned to `alignment` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the two check boxes modify the same variable by binding each one to a getter/setter property that interprets the variable differently. In the template below, two different properties are used:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isLeftAligned">Left
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isRightAligned">Right
</div>
<div>
  Alignment: {{strAlignment}}
</div>
```

But, in the code, `isLeftAligned` and `isRightAligned` both depend on the variable `alignment`:

```
enum Alignment {
  None,
  Left,
  Right,
}
```

```
export class AppComponent {

  private alignment = Alignment.None;

  get isLeftAligned(): boolean {
    return this.alignment === Alignment.Left;
  }
  set isLeftAligned(value: boolean) {
    if (value) {
      this.alignment = Alignment.Left;
    } else {
      this.alignment = Alignment.None;
    }
  }

  get isRightAligned(): boolean {
    return this.alignment === Alignment.Right;
  }
  set isRightAligned(value: boolean) {
    if (value) {
      this.alignment = Alignment.Right;
    } else {
      this.alignment = Alignment.None;
    }
  }

  ...    
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fb33x) for a demo.

An alternative is to use radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Comment: your answer kind of gave me an idea of my own solution and this solution is also right but i cannot implement it in my code because my alignment property is coming from a DTO and that DTO will take the alignment property data into a service and that service is calling a method in asp.net. Anyways thanks for your help

Comment: The answer was for the question as it was asked, in which you have a variable that you can bind to an input element with `[(ngModel)]`.